# How to have values configurable in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am beginning to work on a medium sized AngularJS Application starting from scratch. While practicing I did not understand how to have values configurable in AngularJS application without hard coding them in the JavaScript files. Should I just have the values in a json file which I should then read in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory to store the JSON and use the factory in your controllers to get the JSON object.

Comment: How do I change the values in the factory on the fly while deploying to different environments in an enterprise application?

Comment: What values do you want to configure?

Comment: We have a couple of test environments along with the production environment so each time I deploy the application to these environment I have to change a few values. Can this be automated?